# How to fix dependency issue with partially completed yum update of glibc

Tags: linux, centos, yum, amazon-linux

I attempted to update my production web server this morning (t2 running Amazon Linux) but it failed because I ran out of RAM (php-fpm had it all). I stopped php-fpm to free up some RAM, but the yum update won't complete. The server is running ok, but I'd like to clean up this problem.

```
# yum update
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-106.168.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-106.168.amzn1 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-157.169.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
       Requires: glibc-headers = 2.17-106.168.amzn1
       Removing: glibc-headers-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-106.168.amzn1
       Updated By: glibc-headers-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           glibc-headers = 2.17-157.169.amzn1
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc(x86-64) = ('0', '2.17', '106.168.amzn1')
glibc-devel-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-headers = ('0', '2.17', '157.169.amzn1')
glibc-headers-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc(x86-64) = ('0', '2.17', '106.168.amzn1')
subversion-1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of subversion-libs(x86-64) = ('0', '1.9.4', '2.55.amzn1')
subversion-1.9.5-1.56.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with subversion-1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64
```

Here's the glibc packages that are installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-devel-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64
```

One problem appears to be two different versions of glibc-devel are installed. It also looks like parts of glibc are on version 106 and others are on version 157.

I rebooted the server, which as expected made no difference, but it was worth a shot. I ran the following, with no effect

```
yum-complete-transaction
yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
yum clean all
```

In the past I've had similar problems but with less critical packages. I just remove them all and them install them again. I don't believe this is possible with glibc as so many things depend on it.

I've looked on the Centos forums and one option seems to be downgrading some packages to [downgrade some packages](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5863), but I don't know if there's a better option. Since this is my production server I would appreciate some advice before I attempt this. If this is a good approach which packages should I downgrade? What do I do after I've downgraded, a regular yum update?

Note that I have regular backups and can restore from a recent backup if required, but I'd prefer not to as I'd have to redo some SSL certificate work that was a bit tricky. I plan to move to Ubuntu and use CloudFormation to build the server in the future, so if the server fails I can simply create another, but that's a future task.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion of using rollback. I tried it but it didn't roll things back properly.

I created another instance of the VM and tried to do things manually. Noting from above that I had two versions of glibc-devel I did the following

```
yum remove glibc-devel-2.17-157.169.amzn1.x86_64
yum update glibc-devel-2.17-106.168.amzn1.x86_64
```

At that point I did a "yum check" and it told me there was a problem with subversion as well.

```
yum remove subversion
yum install subversion
yum clean all
yum check
```

This appears to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with glibc-common-2.17-106.1.169.amzn1.x86_64, being a broken installation where all other glibc version where @ 2.17-55.

Running yum reinstall glibc-common-2.17-106.1.169.amzn1.x86_64, triggered the proper dependency resolution and fixed the conflict.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a "yum reinstall" option. Thanks for the tip :)